# hazelcast entry listener on a multinode cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a multi-node hazelcast cluster.  I need to ensure that when a new value is inserted into a map, only one entrylistener/map store gets invoked.  Unless I am having a brain freeze, hazelcast does not do that by default (It would be great if I was wrong about this).  Besides using distributed locks (I do not wish to avoid using listeners/map stores on other nodes), are there any other suggestions to ensure that only one listener/map store ends up executing code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a put only the node owns the key executes the map store operation. 
After a put only the ones which have added itself as listener to a map will receive event.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  Are you referring to entryListener or localEntryListener?